# Was Will Smith really considered for the role of “Mr. Smith?

Tags: casting, mr-and-mrs-smith

Is is true that Will Smith was considered for the role of “Mr. Smith” in Mr. & Mrs. Smith before Brad Pitt was cast as claimed by [this article](http://gostra.com/aw-hell-naw-25-facts-will-smith/)?

Answer (score 3):

It is mentioned in quite a few locations that Will Smith was considered. eg:

- [IMDB Trivia for Mr and Mrs Smith](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0356910/trivia?item=tr0734915)
- [Den Of Geek](http://www.denofgeek.com/movies/14812/50-films-that-nearly-had-very-different-casts)
- [Yahoo Movies](https://www.yahoo.com/movies/looking-back-at-mr-mrs-smith-the-movie-that-96026676222.html)

According to Yahoo Movies:

> Before Brad Pitt and Angelina Jolie were cast in 2005’s sexy action
>   flick Mr. & Mrs. Smith, director Doug Liman contemplated a number of
>   devastatingly attractive pairings: **Will Smith** and Catherine
>   Zeta-Jones. Johnny Depp and Cate Blanchett

As another rumour goes, Nicole Kidman was originally cast for Jane Smith, but Brad Pitt left, [as he felt no chemistry with Nicole](http://www.news.com.au/entertainment/celebrity-life/brad-pitt-cold-on-nicole-kidman/story-e6frfmqi-1226111323609). After Angelina Jolie agreed to star, he came back. In the period between, it is highly likely that they would have considered other actors to play Mr Smith, Will included